# BadArgument error when trying to migrate luis to Azure resource

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to migrate my luis account to Azure resource and i get this error:

```
BadArgument: You have prediction keys assigned in collaborators' apps. These apps will lose access to these keys.
```

What am I doing wrong? What have I to do?

Comment: Can you add this as an issue from inside the LUIS portal - feedback through user voice.

Comment: I did it and i will post the answer (and hopefully the solution) here as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, the problem was that there was a prediction resource assigned to an app.

In LUIS, click on "Manage" in the top bar then under "Application Settings" > "Azure Resources" unassign any resources listed, then try the migration again.

Once the migration process has completed, you can simply re-add any of the unassigned resources by clicking the "Add prediction resource" button and then selecting them from the drop-down menus

Comment: I've already removed my mail adress from the collaborators list of each app using rest api. This automatically removes any resource that has been assigned by me. At the end only 2 luis apps remained, both created by me and none of them has an assigned resource. But when I try to migrate I get the same error saying that there are still prediction keys assigned ... even the error lists only a few resources/apps

Comment: I tried this and migrated, but now my apps are missing. I can't access the apps anymore in LUIS and can't go in and change anything because they're not there. Did you do any step after migrating to get them to show?