# Migrated LUIS to Azure resource, now the LUIS application is missing

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

LUIS kept giving prompts to migrate to Azure for authoring resources because that would be a requirement in August. I went ahead and clicked Migrate, but initially it gave me an error saying

```
BadArgument: You have prediction keys assigned in collaborators' apps. These apps will lose access to these keys.
```

I followed the advice on this thread here: [BadArgument error when trying to migrate luis to Azure resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608043/badargument-error-when-trying-to-migrate-luis-to-azure-resource), where the answer was:

> I had this same issue, the problem was that there was a prediction
>   resource assigned to an app.
>
> In LUIS, click on "Manage" in the top bar then under "Application
>   Settings" > "Azure Resources" unassign any resources listed, then try
>   the migration again.
>
> Once the migration process has completed, you can simply re-add any of
>   the unassigned resources by clicking the "Add prediction resource"
>   button and then selecting them from the drop-down menus

I unassigned the prediction resource, and migrated successfully to Azure and there was an authoring resource there, but when I go back to LUIS to find my apps, that specific app is gone, nowhere to be found. I've logged in as global administrator and other accounts as well, and no application is visible.

I've tried API calls with the app ID and subscription key from before, and I get:

```
This application cannot be accessed with the current subscription
```

Does anyone know where the app is lost and how to get access again? It seems like disconnecting the prediction resource disconnected the app altogether and it is not visible to anyone. How would I be able to get it back?

Comment: Have you confirmed if you have the proper subscription and authoring resource selected from the LUIS portal landing page? I've found sometimes after moving or deleting a resource, it can set me to the old subscription and/or authoring resource by default, making it look like my apps are gone.

Comment: @billoverton yes, I've selected the right subscription and the same authoring resource that was set up during migration. Yet there's no app there

Comment: I'm afraid I have no further ideas.

Comment: Also, have you tried in the preview portal? https://preview.luis.ai/

Comment: Are you able to see other apps in the same subscription? Are you able to see the app on preview.luis.ai portal?

Comment: So an update: After about a week, the resources appeared back. This was especially inconvenient because we had to set everything back up again from a month old backup, and then we see we didn't need to. Everything else was showing up correctly, I guess its a (very unfortunate) glitch in LUIS and migrating to Azure perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a week, the resources appeared back. This was especially inconvenient because we had to set everything back up again from a month old backup, and then we see we didn't need to. Everything else was showing up correctly, I guess its a (very unfortunate) glitch in LUIS and migrating to Azure perhaps